# turtlebot_apps and turtlebot-rviz-launchers package is not being located. What could be the reasons?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS (jade) and tried [navigate](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Make%20a%20map%20and%20navigate%20with%20it) and [gazebo WORLD](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator/Tutorials/hydro/Explore%20the%20Gazebo%20world). Both were working fine. Then, somehow I had to reinstall ubuntu and reinstalled ROS. Since then, I am facing the problem given below. I installed ROS using link text .

```
baban@baban-H81M-DS2:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-jade-turtlebot-apps ros-jade-turtlebot-rviz-launchers

[sudo] password for baban: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-turtlebot-apps
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-turtlebot-rviz-launchers


baban@baban-H81M-DS2:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot-gazebo

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-turtlebot-gazebo : Depends: ros-indigo-gazebo-ros but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: ros-indigo-kobuki-gazebo-plugins but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212427/turtlebot_apps-and-turtlebot-rviz-launchers-package-is-not-being-located.-what-could-be-the-reasons?/) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2015-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-29**:
Please use the *Preformatted Text* button for console copy/pastes (the button with `101010` on it). Otherwise it's unreadable.

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2015-06-29**:
is it fine now? I have kept the console part separately.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-29**:
I already did it for you :). My comment was meant for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your underlying problem is that you're missing some dependencies.  You should make sure that you have turned on universe and multiverse as defined in step 1.1 of the installation: http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu

The other possibility is that you have a conflicting package installed for one of the dependencies.

If you use `-o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes` as an option to apt-get it will give you more information.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on 2015-06-30**:
I checked the 'universe', restricted and 'multiverse', and all three are enabled. I am still unable to figure out the problem. Last time before I un-installed ROS the tutorial codes were working fine.

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2015-07-08**:
This answer doesn't make sense – I thought Gazebo2 (Indigo) and Gazebo5 (Jade) [couldn't be installed simultaneously](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/89#issuecomment-67402826)? Tutlebot isn't ported to Jade yet (see @gvdhoorn's answer below) so you can't run the simulation at all